# What is the difference between these location adverbs?

Tags: grammar

I've been trying for some time to figure out the locational adverbs but no success. There are so many and I am not sure which I should use.

Let's take 'up', 'above' ones for example.

**What is the difference between:**

- droben/daroben
- oben
- über
- hinauf/herauf
- ober
- oberhalb
- aufwärts
- herüber/hinüber

Comment: Forget about *droben/daroben*. It's not in contemporary use. And *herüber/hinüber* actually does not fit into this list. It's like "over here" or "over there", respectively.

Comment: @Em1 Mit `droben`/`daroben` hast du Recht. Aber bei `herüber`/`hinüber` wäre ich mir nicht so sicher. „Come on up!“ könnte vielleicht auch „Komm rüber!“ bedeuten.

Comment: http://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/difference-between-hinter-and-hinten/  ... it doesn't cover all of the ones you mentioned but it might give you some useful background/foundation

Answer (score 7):

**droben/daroben** Very old combination of `da` and `oben`. It means a concrete `oben`.

**oben** means "in some elevated *place*", for example one of the higher shelves of a cupboard, the management or even heaven. It need not mean the highest place.

**über** is mostly used as a preposition, not as an adverb and then not as a locality adverb. The adverb `über` means "more than" or "the rest".

**hinauf/herauf** means a process that results in a specified, higher place than before. It thus gives a *direction*.

**ober** as a single word only used in Austria and there as a preposition having the same meaning as `oberhalb`. As a prefix `ober-` is also used in other varieties of German meaning "superiour/elevated".

**oberhalb** is a preposition meaning "above"="higher or more elevated than something else"

**aufwärts** means "upwards".

**hinüber/herüber** means a process that results in a specified place geographically different from the starting place with the connotation of crossing something.

Comment: Don't forget that *ober* (and its opposite *unter*) is used as an adjective in standard German (i.e. not only in Austria), for instance "Im oberen Fach"

Comment: @Em1 Du meinst sicherlich das Adjektiv `obere`. http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/obere_Adjektiv_obere

Comment: Thank you for the very useful summary.
A couple of small questions.

 - Does this mean oberhalb and über are synonyms (a preposition meaning above smth)?

 - aufwärts should be the same as nach oben?

 - If I am staying up on the stairs and talking to someone below for example. I can say 'Komm zu mir herauf.' Can I also say 'Komm zu mir oben (her).'
`

Comment: `oberhalb` and `über` (in its generic meaning) are synonyms. Beware, that `über` is often used for prepositional objects of verbs. -- `aufwärts` means the same as `nach oben`, but only in an unspecified manner (If you want to make your crush join you in your upstairs room, you can say "Gehen wir nach oben?" but not "Gehen wir aufwärts?"). -- You cannot say "Komm zu mir oben (her)!" as `oben` is a *place adverb*, not a *direction adverb* as `herauf`.